# React native animation

Tags: react-native

I want width of image to increase from 0-100%

So I:

```
this.state = {
    width: new Animated.Value(10)
}
    

componentDidMount(){
    Animated.timing(this.state.width, {
        toValue: new Animated.Value(200),
        duration: 200,
    }).start();
}

render(){
    <View style={Styles.container}>
        <Animated.View style={[{backgroundColor: '#000'}, {width: this.state.width}]}>
            <Image
                center
                style={Styles.image}
                source={require("./../images/homeScreen3.png")}
            />
        </Animated.View>
        .....
}
```

But the image width remain 10. Any suggestions how to complete this task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Animated.timing`, the `toValue` property receives an integer.
You just need to do it as follow:

```
Animated.timing(this.state.width, {
    toValue: 200,
    duration: 200,
}).start();
```